# react-native app is not showing up on ios emulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i'm new to react-native, so was trying react-native default example AwesomeProjects. Everything installed fine and when i ran IOS emulator it wont show my App on startupt .Emulator runs fine, no error show-up. Using

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.54.0
watchman ver- 4.9.0
Homebrew 1.5.8
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 4be0; last commit 2018-03-04)
npm ver-5.5.1
node ver - v8.9.3
Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)
```

Comment: Hi @Ravi. It would be great if you could add the link to the example you're referring to.

Comment: Could you please mention steps that you followed to generate the case! :)
Also, as Artak has mentioned, it would be grateful to share the example with us to get help.